# How do I get attribute XPATHs list using Python?

Tags: python, xpath, attributes

## How do I get attribute XPATHs list using Python?

Thanks for reviewing my question in this forum. Many talked highly about this Python forum, so I am seeking the insight on my issues.

I am trying to list all Xpaths of the input file using Python code developer after reviewing many threads in this forum.

Here is the input XML Message.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
    <country name="Liechtenstein">
        <rank>1</rank>
        <year>2008</year>
        <gdppc>141100</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Austria" direction="E"/>
        <neighbor name="Switzerland" direction="W"/>
    </country>
    <country name="Singapore">
        <rank>4</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>59900</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Malaysia" direction="N"/>
    </country>
    <country name="Panama">
        <rank>68</rank>
        <year>2012</year>
        <gdppc>13600</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Costa Rica" direction="W"/>
        <neighbor name="Colombia" direction="E"/>
    </country>
</data>
```

Here is the Python Code to consume the above XML Message:

```
         

    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
    from lxml import etree
    infile = 'D:\Python_work\eclipse-workspace\My1stPythonP\CountryData.xml'
    output ="D:\\Python_work\\eclipse-workspace\\My1stPythonP\\outfile.out"
    tree = etree.parse(infile)
    root = tree.getroot()
    f = open(output,'w') #open write to file
    count = tree.xpath("count(.//country)")
    print (count)
    f.write("%s\n" %(count))
    xpathf = root.find('.//country')
    print(xpathf.get("value"))
    xpathf = root.find('.//data/country/year')
    print(xpathf.get("value"))
    print (tree.getroot() )
    xmlstr = ET.tostring(root,  method='xml')
    root1 = ET.fromstring(xmlstr)
     
    tree1 = etree.ElementTree(root)
    for e in root.iter():
         f.write("%s\n" %(tree1.getpath(e)))
    f.close()
```

I need this forums help to get the following XPATH List Output using the XML Message input and Python code with lxml. I tried with posted Python Code. It produce the XPATH for XML elements of posted input XML message, but not producing the XPATH for attributes of posted input XML message. The sample missing attribute XPATHs are shown in *italics in below XPATH List Output*

## XPATH List Output

```
/data
/data/country
*/data/country/@name*
/data/country/rank
/data/country/year
/data/country/gdppc
/data/country/neighbor[1]
*/data/country/neighbor[1]/@name*
*/data/country/neighbor[1]/@direction*
/data/country/neighbor[2]
*/data/country/neighbor[2]/@name*
*/data/country/neighbor[2]/@direction*
/data/country[2]
*/data/country[2]/@name*
/data/country[2]/rank
/data/country[2]/year
/data/country[2]/gdppc
/data/country[2]/neighbor
*/data/country[2]/neighbor/@name*
*/data/country[2]/neighbor/@direction*
/data/country[3]
*/data/country[3]/@name*
/data/country[3]/rank
/data/country[3]/year
/data/country[3]/gdppc
/data/country[3]/neighbor[1]
*/data/country[3]/neighbor[1]/@name*
*/data/country[3]/neighbor[1]/@direction*
/data/country[3]/neighbor[2]
*/data/country[3]/neighbor[2]/@name*
*/data/country[3]/neighbor[2]/@direction*
```

1. "tree1.getpath(e)" getting the list of XPATHs, but attribute XPATHS are missing from the list. What is the change in code required to include Xpaths of attributes?

I am looking to extract the value based on XPATH. Using the XPATH based extract, here is the data output , I am looking to report as

```
Country_name  Rank Year Gdppc    Neighbor    Direction
============  ==== ==== =====    ========    ==========

Liechtenstein   1   2008 141100  Austria      East
                                 Switzerland  West

Singapore       4   2011 59900   Malaysia     North

Panama          68  2012 13600   Costa Rica   West
                                 Colombia     East
```

3. What is the way to extract the attribute value based on XPATHs?
4. If there is the name space spec in input file, the above code produce the XPATH list as

   /*
   /*/*[1]
   /*/*[2]
   /*/*[2]/*[1]
   /*/*[2]/*[2]
   /*/*[2]/*[3]
   /*/*[2]/*[4]
   /*/*[2]/*[5]
   /*/*[2]/*[6]

Are there ways to get readable XPATH using Python, when input file contain a namespace spec?

Thanks for your guidance.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you made it a little more complicated than necessary.
Please try it this way:

```
import pandas as pd
rows = []
for country in root.xpath('//country'):
    row = []
    name = country.xpath('./@name')[0]
    rank = country.xpath('rank/text()')[0]
    year = country.xpath('year/text()')[0]
    gdppc = country.xpath('gdppc/text()')[0]
    neigh = ' '.join(country.xpath('neighbor/@name'))
    dirc = ' '.join(country.xpath('neighbor/@direction')).replace("E","East").replace("W","West").replace("N","North")
    row.extend([name,rank,year,gdppc,neigh,dirc])
    rows.append(row)
columns = ["Country_name",  "Rank", "Year", "Gdppc", "Neighbor", "Direction"]
pd.DataFrame(rows)
```

Output:

```
    Country_name    Rank Year   Gdppc   Neighbor               Direction
0   Liechtenstein   1   2008    141100  Austria Switzerland     East West
1   Singapore       4   2011    59900   Malaysia                North
2   Panama          68  2012    13600   Costa Rica Colombia     West East
```

Comment: Thanks. Many folks suggested to use lxml, because it can handle large xml files. Will 'pandas' handle  large XML efficiently ? How do I make the posted xpath list using Python?

Comment: @user2647763 I don't think pandas is intended to deal with xml directly; that's why it's best to process the xml with an xml parser like lxml, and feed the output to pandas. As to the xpath list issue - not sure I understand it and, in any case, you are probably better off posting it as a separate question.

Comment: Thanks. I understand. I am not able to open another question. I am getting "You have reached your question limit" How do I fix this ? Is this voting down cause this issues?

Comment: @user2647763 Never heard of the question limit idea! You probably need to increase your reputation, though not sure. Strangely enough, if you accept this answer and/or upvote it, it will probably increase. But frankly, I'm not so sure about this part of SO....

Comment: Thanks. I did accept answers to many of my old question. You are correct. It bumped up my reputation. It still not allowing to open another question.  What do you men by upvote? How do I do that?

Comment: @user2647763 Every answer has on the side a number (which starts at 0) with an up arrow (click on that to upvote) above the number and a down arrow below (click to downvote). For some reason, you have no option to accept; don't know why.

Comment: @user2647763 Try clicking on the clapping hands and see if it changes anything.

Comment: Clicking on clapping hands not changing anything. I did upvote to many of question's answers. Reders need to upvote to my questions !